# How to transfer specific colors to a raster in r

Tags: r, raster, rasterize

I wonder if it is possible to assign specific colors to the cells of a raster in r.

I know that “rasterize” in the package "raster" allows transferring values to a raster given the coordinates of the given value. However, I wonder if is possible to transfer just a color to the specific position of a cell?

In short, I have a given raster and an external database with three columns (x, y, and color). I would like to transfer the color in the third column to the cell in the raster at the x-y position.

This is the code that I have:

```
library(raster)

BaseRaster<-raster(xmn=1, xmx=4, ymn=1, ymx=4,resolution=1) #create an empty raster

Database<-data.frame(Xcols=c(1.5, 2.5,3.5,   1.5, 2.5,3.5,  1.5, 2.5,3.5) ,
Ycols= c(1.5, 1.5,1.5,   2.5, 2.5,2.5,  3.5, 3.5,3.5),
Cols=c("#FFF423","#FFFF14","#FFE20F","#FFF80A","#FFCB07","#FFE100","#FFEE0B","#FDEE0A","#FFE209"))
```

The question is how do I transfer the colors in the third column of the database to the raster, given the coordinates provided in columns 1 and 2 in the database?
Unfortunately, rasterize does not do the job

```
ColorRaster= rasterize(c(Database$Xcols, Database$Ycols), BaseRaster, Database $Cols)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming BaseRaster is your raster object and database has the color the following should work:

```
plot(BaseRaster, col=colorRampPalette(database$color))(255)
```

for more information refer 
[plot{raster}](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/text)

Comment: Thanks Vishal. I tried your code but I get the following error: "no values associated with this RasterLayer"

Comment: If one fill the raster with say a value of 1 (like: BaseRaster[]=1) and then run your code, one get the following error: "Error in col[x] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: that is not how you create a raster Camilo.
Try BaseRaster <- as.raster(matrix(hcl(0, 80, seq(50, 80, 10)), nrow = 4, ncol = 5))


More help on raster :

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/as.raster.html